# VSFTPD can't download file just after uploading it

Tags: vsftpd

I do not know the specific option to enable in `vsftpd.conf` but when i upload a file permissions are "366" and so I do not have read permissions and can not download. What kind of option should enable for the chmod permissions to be "666" for the file after upload?

Thank you in advance. It must be simple but i can't figure it out.

This is the `vsftpd.conf` without thee commented out lines

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
anon_root=/var/ftp/
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=777
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Comment: can u copy paste your vsftpd.conf file

Comment: change the local_umask to 111 and restart the ftp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vsftpd daemeon will create file permissions as 0777. From that, the local_umask ( 0777 ) is subtracted. As you need to keep file permissions as 666. Changing local_umask value to 111 will do the job.

I suggest to look into this site for more understanding.

[What is Umask and How To Setup Default umask Under Linux?](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you uploaded as anonymous, then it works as designed: to prevent people from sharing files anonymously and get you into trouble in case of anny illegal activity envolved.

The ideas ist that people upload and YOU check the files, then drop them or move them to a public directory and make them accessable to everybody of your users, or the entire internet if you wish.

Your local_umask applies to local users only, so it doesn't apply to anonymous uploads.

In case you uploaded as locally authenticated user, I've missed your confiuration error.

Comment: The sad truth is that I uploaded as a local user.